# Eclipse Pydev interactive console unable to edit previous lines

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have the following problem, I want to change my IDE from Spyder to Eclipse and I like how the interactive console works in Spyder and want to make the one in Eclipse more like it.

When using the console in Spyder I could write `if a == b:` , hit enter and still go up a line and change the `if a == b:`  part. It's not locked in.

In Eclipse, when opening the console with `ctrl + alt + enter` and typing some code in there, it executes every line of code instantly. So when I type `if a == b:` , it becomes unclickable and unchangable. I looked into the preference settings in pydev and couldn't see a way to change the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not really supported right now.

-- it really sends the contents to the backend line by line and doesn't let you edit those lines afterwards.

One option could be typing in an editor and then use `F2` to send a line to the interactive console (it sends a line and then goes to the next one to make it possible to easily send many lines) or select the text that you want (and then use `F2`).